# Object returned from Firebase signIn

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

I have two vue projects against Firebase. The first project is created by webpack-simple and the other with just webpack. When calling signInWithEmailAndPassword in the simple project it returns just -

```
{"uid": "xxxxx", ....}
```

while the other project returns a object with a object

```
{"user": {"uid": "xxxxx", ....}}
```

Is it because the different webpack init or could it be some other settings?

Comment: Do you use the same version of firebase/firebase-auth in both projects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type of vue.js webpack template (vuejs-templates webpack or webpack-simple) should not have any influence on what return Firebase methods.

With version 5.0.0 of the Firebase JavaScript SDK (released on May 8, 2018), the return type signature for `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` has changed: it returns a promise that resolves with a `UserCredential` ([doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth#.UserCredential)) while it used to return a `user` ([doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User)) in the previous version, see https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js

Looking at what you get from the `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` method:

`{"uid": "xxxxx", ....}` corresponds to a `user` object

and

`{"user": {"uid": "xxxxx", ....}}` to a `UserCredential` object.

You are probably using two different versions of the SDK in your two projects (one < 5.0.0 and one >= 5.0.0). You can check that in the `package.json` files.

Comment: Thats true. I must have created my projects on each side of the May 8. Sometimes a good nights sleep mess things up and sometimes you solve problems but anything can happen during a sleep. Thanks for the clarification.